# Sox: Failed reading file: Sorry don't understand .wav size

Tags: asterisk, sox

I want to convert a 44,100 Hz, 24 Bit Mono wav file to aformat that I can play it in asterisk. How can I do this using sox? When I use "Sox filename.wav -t raw -r 44100 -s -w -c 1 filename.sln" I get error "Sox: Failed reading file: Sorry don't understand .wav size". What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoX can't handle 24-bit samples. You will have to use a different program for those.

Try sndfile-convert.

http://itdp.fh-biergarten.de/transcode-users/2005-12/msg00150.html

Comment: SoX can read 24-bit samples. The mailing list message is very old, as is apparently the version used by the asker (the `-w` option was removed in SoX 14.1.0, released in mid-2008; it is now `-b 16`).